# TCPDUMP file (part of a real capture)

Tags: array, beginner, regex, perl

I have been working on this code for quite a while and just want to make sure it is up to good standards. I know many of you will have questions, so as they come up, I will edit my initial question to provide you answers. So any ways to make this code more concise would be great. Be gentle on me, I am only a beginner.

(If you are curious about this projects requirements or the source file I have inputted, if anyone knows how, I can perhaps maybe post a download link to the code or the assignment, let me know if you're interested!)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

# Final project
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

#opens txt file: read mode
open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

#opens output txt file: write mode
open OUT, '>', 'Summary_Report.txt' or die $!;

#open output txt file: write mode
#used to store header 'split' info
open OUTFILE, '>', 'Header.txt' or die $!;

my $i = 0;
$| = 1; #disable output buffering

my $start_time = undef; #undefined to avoid recycling through other time stamps
my $end_time;

my $user = 0;
my $pass = 0;

my $packet_size = 0; #goes with length#

my @header;

my @source_ip;
my @source_port;
my $src_port;
my @src_port;

my @dest_ip;
my @dest_port;
my $destination_port;
my @destination_port;

while (<MYFILE>) { #loops through every line in file
    chomp; #break new line

    #separate pieces of information from TCPDUMP into list
    @header = split (/\s+/, $_);
    print OUTFILE "$.: @header\n\n";

    if (/^\d+:\d+/) {

##############################T I M E###################################

    #defining first 'line & time' as 'special'
    if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) {
        $start_time = $header[0];
        #print "$start_time\n"; ###used as a check###
    }   

    #Used recycling of time stamps to find last one available
    if (/22:28/) {
        $end_time = $header[0];
    }       

############################S O U R C E##################################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from source
    @source_ip = split ('\.', $header[2]);

    #adding ip's together, joining in concatenation by '.'
    $source_ip[$i] = $source_ip[0] . '.' . $source_ip[1] . '.' . $source_ip[2] . '.' .        $source_ip[3];
    #print $source_ip[$i]; (check)

    @source_port = split (':', $source_ip[4]);
    $src_port[$i] = $source_port[0];

#########################D E S T I N A T I O N###########################

    #categorizing each section of ip's from destination
    @dest_ip = split ('\.', $header[4]);

    #adding ip's together, joining in concatenation by '.'
    $dest_ip[$i] = $dest_ip[0] . '.' . $dest_ip[1] . '.' . $dest_ip[2] . '.' . $dest_ip[3];
    #print $dest_ip[$i]; (check)

    @dest_port = split (':', $dest_ip[4]);
    $destination_port[$i] = $dest_port[0];

#############################L E N G T H#################################

    #-1 represents length
    #transferring $header[-1] into new variable for ease of use
    $packet_size = $packet_size + $header[-1];
    #print $packet_size; (check)

    $i++;
    }
}

############################INTERESTING TEXT#############################

my @total_timesplit;

my @s_timesplit = split (':', $start_time);
#print @start_split; check

my @e_timesplit = split (':', $end_time);
#print @end_split; check

$total_timesplit[0] = $e_timesplit[0] - $s_timesplit[0];
$total_timesplit[1] = $e_timesplit[1] - $s_timesplit[1];
$total_timesplit[2] = $e_timesplit[2] - $s_timesplit[2];
#print @total_split; check

#yields average packet size
my $avg_length = $packet_size/$i;
#print $mean; check

##############################SOURCEIP###################################

my %ip_source;
my @ip_source;
%ip_source = map {$_, 1} @ip_source;

my @distinct_src_ip;
@distinct_src_ip = keys %ip_source;

my $sourceip_amt;
$sourceip_amt = @distinct_src_ip;
#print $sourceipnum;

#############################SOURCEPORT##################################

my %port_source;
my @port_source;    
%port_source = map {$_, 1} @port_source;

my @distinct_src_port;
@distinct_src_port = keys %port_source;

my $srcport_amt;
$srcport_amt = @distinct_src_port;
#print $srcportnum;

#############################DESTINATIONIP###############################

my %ip_dest;
my @ip_dest;
%ip_dest = map {$_, 1} @ip_dest;

my @distinct_dest_ip;
@distinct_dest_ip = keys %ip_dest;

my $destip_amt;
$destip_amt = @distinct_dest_ip;
#print $destipnum;

#############################DESTINATIONPORT#############################

my %port_dest;
my @port_dest;
%port_dest = map {$_, 1} @port_dest;

my @distinct_dest_port;
@distinct_dest_port = keys %port_dest;

my $destport_amt;
$destport_amt = @distinct_dest_port;
#print $destportnum;

close MYFILE;

#########################D A T A S E C T I O N###########################

open MYFILE, '<', 'source_file.txt' or die $!;

#I am separating loop to reset values#
while (<MYFILE>) { 

    #finds all instances of USER
    $user++ if /USER/ig;
    #print "user" (use as check)

    #finds all instances of PASS
    $pass++ if /PASS/ig;
    #print "pass" (use as check)

}

#Output summary to new file: overwrite file
print OUT "SUMMARY REPORT:\n\n";

print OUT "# of total lines in the file = $.\n\n\n";

print OUT "Range of time the file encompasses:\n\n
    Starting Time = $start_time\n\n
    Ending Time = $end_time\n\n
    Total Time = @total_timesplit\n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct SOURCE ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct DESTINATION ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct SOURCE ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct DESTINATION ip addresses = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct SOURCE TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of distinct  DESTINATION TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct SOURCE TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Listing of distinct DESTINATION TCP ports = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Total # of times phrases were used:\n\n
USER (variations thereof) = $user\n\n
PASS (variations thereof) = $pass\n\n\n";

print OUT "DETAIL SECTION:\n\n\n";

print OUT "SOURCE IP address activity by port over time:\n\n
    Mean packet size for above = \n\n
    Median packet size for above = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Detail IP address activity by port over time:\n\n
    Mean packet size for above = \n\n
    Median packet size for above = \n\n\n";

print OUT "Any and all interesting text w/in the DATA section of the file:\n\n
    Packet total = $packet_size\n\n
    Number of header lines = $i\n\n
    Average packet size = $avg_length\n\n";

close OUT;              #[                      ]
close OUTFILE;          #[close remaining files ]
close MYFILE;           #[                      ]

my $j = 0;
if ($j == 0) {          
    sleep (1); #dramatic pause!
    print "\n\n   File has successfully run. Please open your Local Disk C: folder to     reveal\n 
                'Summary_Report' file\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Not a question, but I'd appreciate it if you could put the code's intent as the title.  That would help us and help you attract more reviewers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This got a bit longer than expected.

- Don't use `-w` in the shebang line. it serves no purpose if you already `use warnings`.
- Instead of doing error handling for `open` etc. yourself, you should `use autodie`. This is a Core module since perl 5.10.1.
- Don't create “bareword filehandles”, because those are actually global variables. Instead: `open my $out, '>', 'some_file'`. Now `$out` would be the filehandle which you can print to as you're used to: `print $out "stuff"` or better: `print { $out } "stuff"`.
- `$| = 1` disables buffering for the currently selected filehandle (by default, `STDOUT`). Only do this if you need to, as it degrades performance. Also, you should restrict this to the tightest scope neccessary, e.g. `if ($foo) { local $| = 1; print "stuff" }`. But as you have commented out all your debug statements, there is no need for unbuffered output anyway.
- Don't declare all your variables up front – declare them in the tightest scope possible. For example `@header` can be declared *inside* the loop.
- `split /\s+/, $_` is almost equivalent to the default behavior of `split` (which skips over leading whitespace). You probably want to use that instead: `my @header = split;`.
- Instead of `while (...) { ... if ($cond) { STUFF }}`, write:

  ```
  while (...) {
    ...
    next if not $cond;
    STUFF;
  }
  ```

  this avoids an unnecessary level of indentation.
- `if (/^22:28/ && !defined($start_time)) { A } if (/22:28/) { B }` – are you sure the second regex shouldn't be anchored at the beginning as well? In that case, the code could be simplified to:

  ```
  if (/^22:28/) {
    if (not defined $start_time) {
      A;
    }
    B;
  }
  ```
- This line

  ```
  $source_ip[$i] = $source_ip[0] . '.' . $source_ip[1] . '.' . $source_ip[2] . '.' . $source_ip[3]
  ```

  would be better written as `$source_ip[$i] = join '.', @source_ip[0 .. 3]`. This uses an *array slice* and the `join` builtin.
- I am not sure about this piece of code:

  ```
  $source_ip[$i] = $source_ip[0] . '.' . $source_ip[1] . '.' . $source_ip[2] . '.' . $source_ip[3];

  @source_port = split (':', $source_ip[4]);
  ```

  You write into the `$i`-entry of `@source_ip`, and `$i` starts with zero. This means that `$source_ip[4]` is likely `undef`, and should emit some warning. Are you sure you didn't mean `$source_ip[4] = ...;`? But why don't you use another scalar variable for that? `my $ip_string = ...`. Actually, we don't need any extra variable here, and could just write:

  ```
  @source_port = split /:/, join '.', @source_ip[0 .. 3];
  ```
- I am not sure what that line intends to do, I guess you are trying to remove the port part of an IP address? A regex would do a better job than `split`ting and concatenating strings in order to parse the input.
- `$packet_size = $packet_size + $header[-1]` would usually be written as:

  ```
  $packet_size += $header[-1];
  ```
- “Three or more, use a `for`”:

  ```
  for my $i (0 .. 2) {
    $total_timesplit[$i] = $e_timesplit[$i] - $s_timesplit[$i];
  }
  ```
- This is weird:

  ```
  my %ip_source;
  my @ip_source;
  %ip_source = map {$_, 1} @ip_source;
  ```

  Because `@ip_source` was just declared, it is empty. Thus `%ip_source` does not contain *any* keys. You can basically remove that code, as it does nothing.
- To find unique elements in an array, you can use the trick with the hash. Instead of writing that code yourself every time, you can `use List::Util qw< uniq >`, and then find the unique elements like

  ```
  my @unique_items = uniq @items_with duplicates;
  ```
- `… if /USER/ig` – please do not use the `/g` flag in scalar context, as that generally turns the match into an iterator over the current string – but not in this special case, for more complex reasons (which I can explain if you're really interested). But most of the time, this is a bug.
- Instead of multiple `print`s, of double-quoted strings,

  ```
  print OUT "SUMMARY REPORT:\n\n";

  print OUT "# of total lines in the file = $.\n\n\n";
  ```

  you could just use a here-doc:

  ```
  print { $out } <<"END";
  SUMMARY REPORT:


  # of total lines in the file = $.


  Range of time the file encompasses:


      Starting Time = $start_time


      Ending Time = $end_time


      Total Time = @total_timesplit



  ...
  END
  ```

  (but are you really sure that all those newlines in between actually make the output easier to read?)

  A heredoc is introduced with `<<TERMINATOR` where `TERMINATOR` is either a double-quoted `"string"` (in which case the here-doc behaves like a double quoted string), or a single-quoted `'string'`. The terminator must occur on a line of its own. Heredocs cannot be indented. They are better than ordinary strings if you have a multi-line template (as is the case here).
- You might as well remove that condition, as it is always true:

  ```
  my $j = 0;
  if ($j == 0) { ... }
  ```
- I do not think that code like `sleep (1); #dramatic pause!` makes for a good user experience.
- If you find yourself writing the same code again and again (or worse: copy&pasting some code), then you will likely want to write a subroutine. See the introduction in the [Modern Perl Book](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl/chapter_05.html) or in the [official docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html) to learn how to write your own subroutines.

Comment: wow thats a lot thank you! But as you can see, I need some help with the hashes. Do you kind of see what I am trying to do with them at all?